Pass data in to a ViewModel in Swift
I am fairly new to SwiftUI and developing apps on XCode. I have a good experience of other languages but I am struggling to get my head around a few things.
Basically I have a ViewModel set up as an API to pull notifications from my server as below:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


class NotificationsAPI: ObservableObject {
    @Published var notifications: [KXNotification] = []

    let userId = [something here]
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "xxxxxx.php?id=userId") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, _, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
        }
            
        //Convert to JSON
            do {
                let notifications = try JSONDecoder().decode([KXNotification].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.notifications = notifications
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
}
   

On my main view I have the below, but I need to pass the "userId" in to the NotificationsAPI View Model on this view so that it brings through the correct notifications from the server.
import SwiftUI

struct NotificationsView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = NotificationsAPI()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                    Text("Notifications")
                        .font(.poppins(size: 20, weight: .medium))
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    
                    Text("View All")
                        .font(.poppins(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                        .themeForegroundColor(\.gray2)
                        .onTapNavigate(to: AllExercisesView())
                }
                
                Text("Notifications: \(viewModel.notifications.count)")
                    .font(.openSans(size: 12, weight: .regular))
            }
            
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(viewModel.notifications, id: \.self) { notification in
                    LongCardView(
                        image: .web(link: notification.notificationImage),
                        title: notification.notificationTitle,
                        subTitle: notification.notificationDate,
                        icon: "i_icon"
                    )
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}
        

Thanks in advance.
I have tried a number of methods but struggling to get it to work. Would really appreciate some recommendations.

You don't seem to have userid in your view either, but if you did, you could just say fetch(userid) ie. change the fetch method to accept a userid argument.

You have a couple of options here.

You could pass a parameter to the fetch() method. So it will look like func fetch(userId: String(or whatever type you have).
You can learn how parameters in functions work in the documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/functions/.

As a second option you could initialize your viewModel with userId. You can read about initialization in the documentation: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/initialization. Or ask chatGPT to add it for you


The first option is much easier and preferable
